# Why it doesn't update the Date in my database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, vue.js

Below is my code in VueJs that tries to insert the current time to my database.

```
 printDate() {
  var myDate = moment(this.currentDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
  console.log(myDate);

  axios
    .put("http://localhost:9000/api/date/000002", myDate)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

and this one is my code in my server

```
    router.put('/date/:MEMB_N', function (req, res) {
    /* 2019-07-24 11:17:45 */
    let sql = "UPDATE Printing SET PrintDate = ? WHERE MEMB_N = ?";
    myDB.query(sql, [req.body.PrintDate, req.params.Memb_ID], function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.send({
            Success: "True"
        })
    })
});
```

But when I used POSTMAN to try if it works, it successfully inserts the date into my database.

**EDIT:**
Here's the console

[image: img]

**EDIT 2** : POSTMAN result

[image: img2]

Comment: @JaromandaX it doesn't contain any errors, it's just it couldn't update the value

Comment: Date value. I used momentjs to get something like this "2019-07-24 11:26:49" and insert this to my db.

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX sorry but I don't get this: "where's the connection between the value you are sending, and the body property name you've used (PrintDate) "

Comment: Yeah in postman it works but in my vue it doesnt

Comment: You still don't see it? look at the request body in network tab - does it have a "key" called "PrintDate"

Comment: It doesnt have.....

Comment: @Vin can you explain you are sending myDate in put request body and at server side you are getting date from query params why ??

Comment: You are only sending a string literal where your server-side code expects something with a `PrintDate` property. Try `axios.put(url, { PrintDate: myDate })`. To parse the JSON request body, you'll also want to make sure you're using [`app.use(express.json())`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json)

Comment: @TausifShaikh you are wrong, the date is trying to be retrieved from the BODY

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah, but OP said it works via PostMan where they're sending it in the query string. This whole question doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 0):

you have to use header in put request

```
axios
    .put("http://localhost:9000/api/date/000002",
 header:{{"Content-Type": "text/plain"}}
  myDate)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    });
  }
```